# p:dataTable initialization

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a code in which I add elements to a class type list from a method. But whenever Im trying to generate a p:dataTable the corresponding get method of the list can't find out the previous values which I have already added. My code is as below-

```
List<LastToleranceExceed> excptn = new ArrayList<LastToleranceExceed>();

public void ret_approve(FlPendingList fl)throws SQLException{

  String q = "----My Query----";
  PreparedStatement pq=cn.prepareStatement(q);
  ResultSet rsq=pq.executeQuery();

  while(rsq.next()){
    excptn.add(new LastToleranceExceed(unit_name,energy_name,
                                       consump_id,date_list,
                                       shift_list,
                                       Edit_Quantity,
                                       Quantity,
                                       uom_list,
                                       violation));
  }

public List<LastToleranceExceed> getExcptn() throws SQLException{
  return excptn;
}
```

In Xhtml :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{flApproval.excptn}" 
             var="vio" 
             id="dt2" 
             rendered="#{flApproval.dt_show}">

  <p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      Date
    </f:facet>
    #{vio.activitydate}
  </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

What is the problem of this code? how I can get the values which I have added? Plz help

Comment: How are you updating the table? Is it inside <h:form> ?

Comment: @ jedrus07: yes, it is inside a <h:form id="df2"> and Im updating it via a commandButton as update=":df2:dt2"

Comment: Can you post the code for your button and for the bean? It could be a problem with the scope of the bean not beaing @ViewScoped or anything that lives past the request.

Comment: @jedrus07: My problem is solved, thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When is `ret_approve` method called, probably it's after the data table initializes.
You can try applying `@PostConstruct` annotation on `ret_approve`.